# Pull right and left not working on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a bootstrap 36 grid column.
Sidebar on the left and content on the right.
When I use pull right/left it works only on desktop?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                      
        <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-9 col-xs-36 pull-right">
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="col-md-27 col-xs-36 pull-left">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On mobile the sidebar still shows first. Why?

**Okay I have customized my grid, you can do that on the bootstrap website. Please stop saying I can't.**

Comment: Bootstrap is a 12 grid system

Comment: Hey where are these classes came from `col-md-27, col-xs-36` if you are using bootstrap you should know its a 12 grid layout

Comment: No I have customized it.

Comment: Please you can give your demo as jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

as you have used `col-xs-36`  that means this column all take 100% of available width then why you want to use `pull-right`  or `pull-left`, reduce the number of column and then it will be ok

```css
.box{padding-top: 30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                      
        <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-9 col-xs-6 pull-right box">
          <p>abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd </p>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 pull-left box">
          <p>abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd abd </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No.. I have customized it on the website.

Comment: I know you customized it but on mobile you are adding all grids like col-xs-36  then if add pull-right it will stay at same position

Comment: The second column should get above the first column right?

Comment: no it will not because of upper column have col-xs-36(means all grid width means width 100%). let assume you use 36 grids in your task and 36 grids means width 100% so in mobile if you add col-xs-36 it will take 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                      
        <div id="sidebar" class="pull-right col-xs-9">
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="pull-left col-xs-27">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: col-xs-36 means it will be having 100% width in mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

> On mobile the sidebar still shows first. Why?

To explain it.. You have a bootstrap `row` whose work is to align all the elements inside it to its respective widths as mentioned in `col-*`. And also if the space is not sufficient to display all the elements in a row then it will push them one below the other. That is how it is called responsive, And its the default behavior of Bootstrap.

Now you said you customized the code to have `36` grid system and I am aware of it.

Now in the below code.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">                      
        <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-9 col-xs-36 pull-right">
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="col-md-27 col-xs-36 pull-left">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You say both the divs inside the `row` must occupy `36`columns in extra small devices. So as you mentioned you have `36` grid system it means `36` = `100%` width.

As explained above the `row` cannot stuff both the div's in one line as both are demading 100% width. So it moves them one below the other.

Side bar comes on top because its the one mentioned first in the hierarchy.

Hope this is helpful

**Edit 1:** If your intention is to show the sidebar on left and then the container on right in all devices... And on mobile devices show the container first and then side bar.. with the help of `@media` queries you can win this. Working snippet below. Also here is the **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/627po4e4/2/)**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #sidebar {
    float: right !important;
  }
  #content {
    float: left !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="content" class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 pull-right">
      container
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 pull-left">
      Sidebar
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I get it now. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @hello123 If you can let me know the desired behavior then we can solve this. Like what must happen to your side bar in mobile devices? you want to show it?? hide it?? toggle display on some button? etc etc

Comment: I want the content to show first on mobile and then the sidebar.

Comment: @hello123 just reorder the position of sidebar and the container... Working fiddle here...https://jsfiddle.net/627po4e4/  resize the result window to effect..

Comment: No I want the sidebar on the left on desktop

Comment: I want the sidebar on the left not the container:P That is the whole problem.

Comment: @hello123 upated my answer, let me know if this was helpful.. This was indeed a good exercise   :)

Comment: Hey sorry, I can't change the html markup. But I appreciate the effort.